# How do I make sure that the function under test is the only function being called?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'm using Python, if that's relevant.

As I understand it, a unit test is a test of the smallest portion of code that is relevant to a single use case. Often times this is a single function or method.

So when I'm testing my function, I do not want to test any functions that it's calling. When writing tests, that's reasonably easy to do: Just concern yourself with the logic that your function is doing.

But when I have the following situation:

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number <= 1:
        return False

    for element in range(2, number):
        if number % element == 0:
            return False

    return True

def extract_primes(lst):
    return [item for item in list if is_prime(item)]
```

I'm confused about how a test for `extract_primes` would look like.

```
def test_extract_primes():
    lst = [0, 1, 2]
    result = extract_primes_from_list(lst)
    assert result == [2]
    # and some more similar tests for empty lists, lists with only primes
    # and lists with no primes
```

But now I'm just implicitly testing whether `is_prime` is doing its work correctly. And when `is_prime` has a bug, it will also cause the test for `extract_primes` to fail, which beats the point of unit tests, where you want to quickly spot the single point of failure.

So it seems to me, that I shouldn't be calling `is_prime` in the first place. So I end up with something like this:

```
@unittest.mock.patch("path.to.module.is_prime")
def test_extract_primes(mock_is_prime):
    mock_is_prime.return_value = True
    lst = list(range(10))
    result = extract_primes(lst)
    assert result == lst
    for i in lst:
        assert mock_is_prime.called_with(i)  # not sure if correct method name
```

But this is tiresome and inflexible at best. I cannot cause `mock_is_prime` to return different values inside of the same test, unless I create a construct like:

```
bool_list = [True, False, True]
mock_is_prime.side_effect = lambda x: next(bool_list)
```

But that gets *even more* verbose. And as the number of function calls within the function under test increases, so does the stupid amount of boilerplate code to patch away those functions.

When I try to look for answers on the internet, I mostly get Java/C# dependency injection instructions, where they tell you to pass the correct needed object as parameter, and just create a dummy of that object for the method you're testing. Or I get debates about whether or not to test private methods. And that's fine, I understand those things. But I can't for the life of me figure out what to do with functions that depend on other function calls. Should I simply inject those functions?

```
def extract_primes(lst, is_prime_function=is_prime):
    return [item for item in list if is_prime_function(item)]
```

And pass a dummy `is_prime` function into `extract_primes` under test? That just looks stupid and litters the function signature with weird parameters. And it's practically no different from patching the function away in the amount of work required. It just removes a single `@patch` statement from the test.

So should I not be patching away functions in the first place? And if not, at what point does a function become worth patching away anyway? Only when it's manipulating the system? Or also when it's from a completely separate module?

I'm a little lost.

Comment: This might be more suited to [programmers.SE](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also: this doesn't answer your question, but --  `extract_primes = partial(filter, is_prime)`

Comment: @tzaman I'm well aware. I just needed example code. The actual code is much more difficult to quickly explain in a question. Everybody knows what primes are; so I'll use a question on primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking: It depends entirely on your design, but your initial attempt seems reasonable.

Assuming `is_prime` and `extract_primes` are both part of your class / module's public interface, they should both be tested. At that point, you want to test `extract_primes` as a black-box, i.e. just ensuring that it *fulfills its contract*: give it a list and it returns the primes. The fact that it's using `is_prime` internally is an implementation detail your unit test code shouldn't concern itself with.

The point of unit tests isn't necessarily that ONLY the earliest failure should trigger (of course, it's great if you can manage that); it's quite possible that a lot of dependent things fail if you break something high enough upstream. If `is_prime` is broken, then it's perfectly valid to see a test failure for `extract_primes` too, but just looking at the list of test failures is enough to immediately identify the root cause.

Also, this way you can do things like: try out other prime-testing functions, replace the list comprehension with a generator expression, or other refactors etc. under the hood *without* needing to change your test code.

Mocking should be reserved for *external* dependencies; patching every call that any function makes is ridiculously verbose, ties test code to implementation far too tightly, and doesn't really get you anything.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is a good rule of thumb that when you reach a point where the best practices don't work for you then the problem occurred much earlier than that point. In your case you don't know what to do because you have two public methods calling one another. This is usually indicative of the fact that they don't belong in the same class. For instance a function that filters a list based on a predicate doesn't really have anything to do with prime numbers. This shouldn't be functionality provided by this class. If this is something that you are doing very often then you can create a list utils class that has a filter method. I think that testing the two methods, `is_prime` and `filter_list`, should be very easy.

In general classes should be designed to provide a set of functionality to a user. A class shouldn't be it's own user. That creates many problems not the least of which is the problem you encountered. Of course there are exceptions to this rule and the best design should be judged on a case by case basis but I find this to be a good rule of thumb.

Comment: Of course a class can be its own user. Java does this all the time with getters and setters. And consider a class `ChessBoard` which has the methods `do_move` and `is_move_legal`, both of which are public. The `do_move` method calls `is_move_legal`, because the board cannot perform an illegal move. But I'm not even using a class in the above example; only procedural code.

Comment: Again getters and setters are almost always indicators of bad design. It is pretty much a less offensive way of declaring your members public.

Comment: Your chess board example is also problematic. Why do both users of your class and your class itself have to validate the move? It would be better if is_move_legal were private and do_move would throw an exception if the move was illegal. But again this should be judged on a case by case basis and you might have a compelling reason but in most cases you won't.

Comment: I'm sorry, what? Are you insane? Getters and setters are incredibly *good* design in Java. If you have a class `Point`, you *want* it to have a `getX()` and `getY()`. And the `ChessBoard` example is absolutely fine. I *want* to expose the ability to verify whether a move is legal to the user, because it's a damn handy convenience function. It's better than `try { board.do_move(); } catch { legal = False; } else { legal = True; board.undo_move(); }` to verify whether a move is legal in any case.

Comment: Point is different. Point is just a structure for aggregating the members. It's functionality is just getX and getY. Let's say ChessBoard has a private array of squares providing a user with access to it is an egregious violation of encapsulation. Regarding the is_legal you are right it is useful functionality but should be in a different class there is no reason for the board to know the rules of chess. And yes, quite insane :)

Comment: @CarmenBiancaBakker While I agree "*getters and setters are almost always indicators of bad design*" sounds a little harsh, there's no need to call people insane.  Broadly speaking, Benjy's right, e.g. there's *likely* no need to expose a method like `is_move_legal` to callers.  Your try/catch example is somewhat contrived; callers wouldn't need to "undo" the board, that's the board's job.  In any case, data-structure design decisions are tangential to this question.  The point, that you might want to re-examine earlier decisions when you run into testing difficulty, is sound.

Comment: @dimo414 Callers *would* need to undo the board, because the `do_move` method successfully executed and the move was therefore legal. But now they ended up with a modified board, which isn't what they wanted when they tried to verify the legality of the move, so they have to undo the move. Note that I wrapped it up in an `else` statement, not a `finally` statement, where `else` equals "execute this if and only if no error was raised". In any case, the decision to make `is_move_legal` public isn't insane by any stretch of the imagination. And if the example prime code in the question should(c)

Comment: (c) be re-examined, those are some insane coding standards. The example code in this question is absolutely fine, and a regular example of how pure functions (static methods) are called in normal code bases. In this case it was a needless convenience function, but you might imagine a different function that will have some special case for prime numbers, and needs a function to be able to verify whether a given integer is a prime number.

Comment: I think this discussion has digressed quite a bit but if we are discussing the ChessBoard, I would suggest having a board in charge of actually storing the pieces and a ChessGame class which knows which moves are legal based on  the rules of the game. But again as I said loosely coupled functions is a good design practice. But all design rules apply better in certain cases than others. IMHO the case in your question is a classic example of needlessly coupling list filtering with primality testing.

Comment: @CarmenBiancaBakker I would be happy to debate `ChessBoard` design decisions with you if you'd like to post a question about that.  However for the purpose of this question suffice to say you *could* successfully implement a `ChessBoard` class without exposing `is_move_legal` to callers.  What Benjy and I are suggesting is that such a design might be easier to test.  Seeing as you're coming here asking for help on how to test things, maybe take that suggestion a little more seriously.  And the only one throwing around "insane" here is you.  Please stop.

Comment: The point of the `ChessBoard` example was not to debate the actual design of a chess game; the point was to illustrate that it's completely normal to rely on a public method within your own class. A different example, then. We have a `Circle` that has a `getRadius` getter. We could add a `getDiameter` getter that *depends* on the already-public `getRadius` method. Or we have a `Game` class where the public `start` method depends on its public `resetSound`. There is absolutely nothing wrong with a public method depending on a another public method of its own class, as @BenjyKessler suggested.

Comment: @CarmenBiancaBakker *It depends*.  As we've been saying, if you run into difficulty testing your code, interdependency could be part of the problem.  We're speaking in generalities and you're coming back with absolutes.  If you're looking for an absolute answer, I'm afraid their isn't one.

Comment: When you need to test *private* method there 95% chance that this method should be a public method of a private collaborator. Maybe `is_move_legal` is a public method of `ChessRules()` class used as `ChessBoard`'s collaborator. Single responsibility principle rule... when a class do too much works split it and maybe your design will be improved and become more testable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no easy answer, short of "write really well structured code", which of course, is hard.  I'll try to help shed some light on the subject by going through your question piece by piece.

> As I understand it, a unit test is a test of the smallest portion of code that is relevant to a single use case. Often times this is a single function or method.

This is broadly correct, but the primary goal is to test the *interface* of that code; that is to say, given certain inputs, do you get the expected outputs.  You don't want to care about *how* that block of code does what you want (if you do, you start writing [change detector](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2015/01/testing-on-toilet-change-detector-tests.html) tests).

> I do not want to test any functions that [my function is] calling.

Not quite; you don't want to care about what functions the code being tested calls.  As far as your test is concerned, you don't care if it is a hard-coded mapping of inputs to outputs, or if it goes out and does a Google search* and parses the first result, as long as the behavior is what you expect.

Notice that your `is_prime` function depends on the behavior of other "functions" too - `<=`, `range()`, `%`, and `==` all have to behave a certain way for your `is_prime` function to work correctly.  That isn't a bad thing!  You can be confident the functionality `is_prime` depends on is working correctly because Python has already tested it.  Whether they're tested at the same time or not doesn't really matter.

> I'm just implicitly testing whether `is_prime` is doing its work correctly.

Not really.  There's nothing about `extract_primes()` that requires it use `is_prime()`, in fact you might very well discover a better algorithm for this behavior later and want to swap it out.  You want to test these two functions separately because otherwise your tests only work on the assumption that `extract_primes()` calls `is_prime()`.

If there *is* some reason in your actual use case that `extract_primes()` must rely on `is_prime()`, then you are likely over-coupling your code.  Consider, as others have suggested, separating your predicate-like behavior from your filter-like behavior, so that the filtering works on any predicate.

> when `is_prime` has a bug, it will also cause the test for `extract_primes` to fail, which beats the point of unit tests, where you want to quickly spot the single point of failure.

Very true, and this is generally something you want to try to avoid.  But all code is built upon other code, and it's impossible to always have one and only one test fail.  If something deep in your code breaks, everything that depends on it will break too.  One solution is to have layers of tests; unit and integration tests at a minimum, but you can also have layers inside of that, e.g. test your utility code first, and only test dependant code once those tests all pass.

> [Injecting functions] is tiresome and inflexible at best.

Definitely.  Don't do that (normally).  In fact, a pretty good sniff-test of your code is "Do I have to do strange, cumbersome things with my code in order to write good tests?"  If so, your design probably merits revisiting.

Of course, this isn't always possible.  You've seen mocking, stubbing, monkey patching and dependency injection, all of which are tools for dealing with difficult-to-test code, but these are all tools for when you can't reliably *just test the interface*.

In other words, first try to write clean, loosely coupled code.  Then, try to test the interface of each component in isolation.  When you can't reliably do that, start looking at mocking and dependency injection and so on.

<sub>*You certainly might care about this from a performance or test stability perspective, but that's a separate issue.  As far as that individual test is concerned, it doesn't care.</sub>

Comment: I kind of understand, but I'm still kind of puzzled. This is especially confusing because so much of unit testing instructions are extremely OOP-bound, and Python code mixes all sorts of styles really easily. [This blog post](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/) describes the issue relatively clearly. If I have a function that calls a function that calls two more functions, it becomes incredibly difficult to test the first function. And because all of the functions are pure functions, there's no dependency injection to be done other than live patching.

Comment: @CarmenBiancaBakker The core point I'm trying to get at is "don't worry whether your function calls other functions unless you have to."  If you need to expose `is_prime` and `extract_primes` functions, then you should have tests for both of them.  If you find yourself writing a lot of redundant tests, change detectors, or flaky tests, that's a strong suggestion you should revisit your design, such that you can provide both behaviors without them being so dependent on each other.  For the example you've provided, defining a generic filter method and testing that would be cleaner.